# XAML, MVVM and TwoWay Data Binding

Tags: wpf, unit-testing, xaml, mvvm, uwp-xaml

I have the following XAML. I'm using UWP (Universal Windows Platform) but the problem I'd like to describe also applies to other XAML frameworks such as WPF:

```
<!-- MyVM is a ViewModel -->
<AutoSuggestBox
    QueryIcon="Find"
    TextChanged="{x:Bind MyVM.FilterTextChanged}" 
    Text="{x:Bind MyVM.FilterText, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

This is how it works: when the user types text in the `AutoSuggestBox`, `MyVM` ViewModel is informed about every key stroke and filters data using `FilterText`.

This is how `MyVM` looks like:

```
// Uses INotifyPropertyChanged from MVVMLight
private string filterText;
public string FilterText
{
    get { return filterText; }
    set { Set(ref filterText, value); }
}

public async void FilterTextChanged()
{
    await LoadData(); // uses FilterText to filter data
}
```

The problem arises when I need to modify `FilterText` value, for example to clear it or to set a pre-defined filter. Thanks to the TwoWay binding, the text in the `AutoSuggestBox` is displayed correctly but as a "side-effect" the `FilterTextChanged` method is called (because the text has changed). I don't want this "side-effect". It is bad from two reasons:

1. It makes the ViewModel dependent on XAML in the View. What I mean by that is that although I don't call `FilterTextChanged`, it is called anyway when I set the `FilterText` value just because it is TwoWay-bound in XAML.
2. It makes automated unit testing impossible. Without XAML, the ViewModel behaves differently: the `FilterTextChanged` method is not called when I set a `FilterText` value.

This is a general problem with XAML, MVVM, and TwoWay binding, not restricted to the specific example with `AutoSuggestBox`.

How to solve this problem? The main question for me is how to unit test it?

Answer (score 0):

> The problem arises when I need to modify FilterText value, for example to clear it or to set a pre-defined filter. Thanks to the TwoWay binding, the text in the AutoSuggestBox is displayed correctly but as a "side-effect" the FilterTextChanged method is called (because the text has changed). I don't want this "side-effect".

If I understand your question, you just do not want the `FilterTextChanged` called when you empty the AutoSuggestBox or set a default value for it. If so, you do not need to use `TextChanged` to trigger the `FilterTextChanged` method, you could call it when the property value changed.

For example:

```
<AutoSuggestBox QueryIcon="Find" Text="{x:Bind MyVM.FilterText, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

```cs
private string filterText;
public string FilterText
{
    get { return filterText; }
    set
    {
        if (value != string.Empty || value != "default value")
        {
            FilterTextChanged();
        }
        filterText = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("FilterText");
    }
}

public async void FilterTextChanged()
{
    await LoadData(); // uses FilterText to filter data
}
```

Comment: Then when a user clears the text from the textbox, FilterTextChanged would not get called and results would remain on UI from the previous search. I would suggest calling the FilterTextChanged method from the setter when "value != filterText" (previous value). Whenever needed to revert to default set the private variable "filterText" to default or an empty string, and raise the property changed for the binding.

Comment: Thanks @Xavier and @ParameterX. It looks like the key is to call `RaisePropertyChanged` in the `FilterText`'s setter rather than to rely on TwoWay binding. There is one small issue with your approach though: the `FilterTextChange` method is `async` but in the `FilterText`'s setter it's not awaited. I know that C# properties can't be `async`. Should I leave it as it is? What are consequences of not awaiting an `async` method here? (for now, I can see a warning in VS)

Comment: Any solution for the async method called in the setter? I think this is not as a small issue as I thought. If a method is async, it should be awaited. It makes the suggested solution not applicable.

Comment: You used `async void` method, you did not have to use `await` when you call `FilterTextChanged` method, because you've used `await` in its method.

Comment: The reason why the `FilterTextChanged` method is `async void` rather than `async Task` is that in my original code it was bound in XAML to `TextChanged`. When it is called from code, shouldn't it return `async Task` and be awaited?